# How an HTTP proxy knows when to close the connection

Tags: java, http, proxy

This question applies only for HTTPS requests.

Lets divide the problem in 3 areas.

1. The origin. This is the user sending an HTTPS request.
2. The proxy. This will handle the request, forward it to the remote and vice-versa.
3. The remote. This is the server where the request is supposed to arrive.

When you make an HTTPS request through a proxy, this is what happens:

1. Origin sends with HTTP (this is not encrypted):

   CONNECT remote.url:443 HTTP/1.1
   ...
2. Proxy replies:

   HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
3. Origin sends the request to the proxy, totally encrypted:

   Cﾦￔi ﾧJ￁,ﾀﾯH;ﾎUﾬ*ﾈﾷ#cR{gﾘ ﾷ�ￄﾞWuﾠY<u#1ﾅ￳#j￴iￗHﾱￗk...
4. Proxy takes it as it is, and it forwards it to remote:

   Cﾦￔi ﾧJ￁,ﾀﾯH;ﾎUﾬ*ﾈﾷ#cR{gﾘ ﾷ�ￄﾞWuﾠY<u#1ﾅ￳#j￴iￗHﾱￗk...
5. Remote replies, it is also totally encrypted:

   cR{gﾘ ﾷ�ￄﾞWuﾠY<u#1...
6. Proxy passes this to the origin:

   cR{gﾘ ﾷ�ￄﾞWuﾠY<u#1...
7. Origin knows how to decrypt this and it is happy to receive the response.

The question is, how does the proxy knows that the response is terminated?. The proxy is just reading streams, and cannot know the end of it. Moreover, it cannot read HTTP headers to know the length because they are encrypted.

I am facing this issue in Java and I don't know how to deal with that.

Answer (score 2):

The encrypted communication goes from the client to the server, and the proxy is unaware. However the byte stream traverses two TCP connections:
The one from the client to the proxy, and the one from the proxy to the server.

If either one of them gets terminated the proxy can close the other. Termination is indicated by the network stack, and the proxy just forwards that message into the other connection.

So if the client hangs up, the proxy would notice a hangup on client side and terminate it's connection to the server. On the server side a termination on client side is noticed. And if the server hangs up, the same happens in the other direction.

Now the question would be to figure out in Java whether the connection was lost. Typically the proxy application should either be waiting for data or writing data to the other stream. Without having created the code myself, I strongly believe if the network stack communicates that a connection is down it would resolve in an IOException, either thrown during the read operation from the input stream or thrown during the write operation for the other stream.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this please?: 'Termination is indicated by the network stack'

Answer (score 1):

Http connection is nothing but network connection between two sockets. To end an HTTP connection socket.close() needs to be called. Normal HTTP connections (not pipelined) use this method.

There are multiple scenarios how it is done. Let's take a simple example to emulate your scenario.

- Client calls proxy server. That is a HTTP connection between client &
  proxy, Let's call it **connection A**.
- Proxy calls destination using new separate HTTP connection. Let's
  call it **connection B**.
- Destination sends encrypted data to proxy via **connection A**.
- Proxy forwards the data packet to client via **connection B**.
- Client reads the data & decrypts it. It gets to know response payload
  size from **Content-Length** header.
- Once client is done reading that many bytes, it decides to call
  socket.close() on **Connection A**.
- Proxy detects **connection A** got closed. So it doesn't need to maintain
  **connection B** to destination & closes it.

So both HTTP connections got terminated. And it didn't need proxy to
read encrypted data.

Comment: It looks the part where the proxy detects the connection got closed is not that easy. At least my proxy is not aware of this for some reason. Maybe I have a bug in the code.

Comment: Proxies would have different implementations. And I described a simple scenario above. But in general, proxy would store a mapping between a live client connection (connection A) & live destination connection (connection B). So if any one them terminates, proxy can terminate the other connection. That is a basic job of proxy.

Comment: @aatwork 'Proxies would have different implementations' -> the question was how a proxy knows when to terminate the connection.